# std system is run after going to next line c++

Tags: c++

here is piece of my code:

```
void Espresso::run()
{
  std::system("/home/espresso-ab-1.0/src/espresso espresso.in > espresso.out");
  std::string line;
  std::ifstream myfile ("espresso.out");
  if (myfile.is_open())
  {
    while ( getline (myfile,line) )
    {
      std::cout << line << '\n';
    }
    myfile.close();
  }
}
```

I am wondering if above code first run the system command and fill completely "espresso.out" file and then go to the the next line of reading it. 
if not, how I can make sure file is fully printed before going to read it.

NOTE: I am restricted to use C++03.

**Thanks for your prompt answer.** I want to Update my question by: 
- Is it a thread safe method as well?

Comment: `std::system` will block until the command is finished, so yes, the `espresso.out` file will be "ready" by the time you try to open it.

Comment: You could use the [`popen`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/popen.html) and read the output from the command directly instead. Though then you need to use the C `FILE*` "stream".

Comment: @szczurcio: Please use the _answer section_, not the _comments section_ for answering questions.

Comment: OP, thanks for correctly spelling "espresso"!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Is this worth posting as an answer? From "common knowledge" I know that what I said in the comment holds, but I feel like an answer should provide some sort of reference, and not "this is true because I, random guy on SO, say so".

Comment: @szczurcio: Yes, if it answers the question, it is an answer, and should be posted as such (if you haven't the time to post a full answer, that's fine - simply don't!). Comments are not subject to review queues, downvotes, or editing. If your "mini-answer" were incorrect, we would have no way of correcting it. Please use the Q&A model as it was intended. Ta :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the command will be fully completed before the `std::system` call returns.

Answer (score 3):

`std::system` is not an async function. So for example, if you'd run:

```
std::system("sleep 5");
std::cout << "Foo" << std::endl;
```

"Foo" will be displayed after 5 seconds. 
Of course if you're on linux you could run it like this `std::system("sleep 5 &")`. Then the sleep command will run as a background process and the code following the system call will execute immediately. 
Although I encourage you not to use this function. Calling system functions by their name is dangerous. Imagine what would happen, if someone replaced the sleep binary in your system with their own program. Conclusion: your program will hang until the system command is completed. So your file will be ready.